# In java, how can I read data from file and create a collection of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I am trying to run Junit Parameterized test. Following is how Junit suggests to add data to collection of arrays.

```
Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 } };  
return Arrays.asList(data);
```

This however requires user to add the data in the code. I want to read data from file (about 300 lines) and convert it into collection of Arrays. How can I do that ?

Here is the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;



@RunWith(value=Parameterized.class)
public class UrlParameterizedTest {

    private String url;
    public static ArrayList<String>dataArray=new ArrayList<String>();
    static File directory = new File(".");
    public static String fileToRead;

    public UrlParameterizedTest(String url){
        this.url=url;
    }
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() throws Exception {

        try {
            fileToRead=directory.getCanonicalPath()+"\\Data\\LinkChecker.csv";
            loadDataFile(fileToRead);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    Object[][]data=new Object[dataArray.size()][];
      *******   //convert dataArray to data here.************
        return Arrays.asList(data);

    }

    @Test
    public void testURLs() {
        System.out.println("Parameterized Number is "+url);
    }

    public static void loadDataFile(String dataFile) throws Exception {
        dataArray.clear();
        //if data_file is absolute, use this
        try
        {
            // Open an input stream
            // Read a line of text
            String line="";
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFile));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                dataArray.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
            System.out.println("The data file length is "+ dataArray.size());
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println ("Unable to read from file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more detailed ?

Comment: @TechExchange : I guess OP wants to read inputs( 1,2,3,4 ) from file

Comment: @TechExchange: My questions is based on https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit. As Bhavik pointed out, I want to read {1},{2},{3},{4} from a CSV file. According to the above mentioned ref., Parameter's data method must return a collection of Arrays. Now, I already have a method that reads data from csv and puts that into an arrayList. I want to convert that arrayList into Object[][]data. In short, 300 lines in csv file should result in 300 parameterized test methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use Apache Commons `FileUtils.readFileToString` to read the file to a string. Then you will need to parse the file into the collection of arrays. We cannot help you on how to parse the file and we don't know the contents.

[FileUtils.readFileToString](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: @Bhavik: List is a good option. How to turn that list into a collection of arrays ?

Comment: That depends on your file. You need to parse or group the lines into arrays. We don't know if each line is a comma-separated list of values or if you are going to combine a set of lines into an array or if each line is a single entry in the array. You have to figure SOME of these things out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in a file, one under the other. Use a scanner to read them as strings and then convert them to numbers (I assumed that they should be float numbers).
Something like this:

```
ArrayList<Float> numbers = new ArrayList<Float>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
    float value = Float.parseFloat(nextLine);
    numbers.add(value);
}
scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve strings from a File you could use something like the follow code; then you could retrieve data from your ArrayList and put them in your array (using "toArray()" method provided by Class ArrayList).

```
ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String >();
String filePath = path + "/" + fileName;

FileInputStream fin = null;
            try {
                fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println (e.toString()); 
                System.out.println("File " + fileName + " not found.");
            }

            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fin);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine = null;


            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                strings.add(strLine);
            }

            in.close();
```